Generate static id in the generated URL, when using api gateway with localstack and sam template
Is is possible to generate  custom id for the api gateway generated url, when using SAM template and localstack.
I have read the documentation provided by localstack, where they have mentioned that creating the custom id is possible, when using the create-rest-api command. (Reference)
But in the official document, they have not mentioned how to add this custom id when deploying through samlocal deploy.
But I tried the steps mentioned here, but that did not work for me. In my template the type was

Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'

and not

Type: AWS::Serverless::Api

Can anyone help me on this.

Instead of
sam deploy

you can use:
samlocal deploy

samlocal is a AWS SAM wrapper for use with LocalStack
